# i am importing my components to the app.js but i get a blank page in the the dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar.js';
import Merch from './components/Merch/Merch.js';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer.js';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <Navbar />
        <Merch />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you remove remove these `<Navbar /> <Merch /> <Footer />` and write a simple "hello world" there and see if it shows hello world?

Comment: @AjeetShah yes it shows , its a problem in the components or what because i change every possibility and i still have the blank page

Comment: Ok. So the problem is in component. Which one? Can you try removing each one by one to find out which component is problematic. And, if there are problems in component, how can we help unless we see the code written inside the component? Also, can you create a Code Sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/) and share its link with us to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @AjeetShah thank you for your help , it was a problem in the components , I forget to add a return cuz it didn't show me any problem in the dom , so I fix it now , thank u very much